# Swashbuckle SchemaFilter for api operation parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums, swagger, swashbuckle

I have succesfully created `ISchemaFilter` to extend *swagger.json* enum property definitions for code generation purposes as described [here](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1234). Here is my current `SchemaFilter.Apply` method:

```
public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
{
    if (context.SystemType.IsEnum)
    {
        var names = Enum.GetNames(context.SystemType);
        var values = Enum.GetValues(context.SystemType);
        var desc = "";

        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            var intValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(value.GetType()));
            desc += $"{intValue}={value},";
        }
        desc = desc.TrimEnd(',');
        schema.Extensions.Add("x-enumNames", names);
        schema.Extensions["description"] = desc;
    }
}
```

`SchemaFilter` works properly on my model definitions where model class has member with enum type. Following there is example of output: `resolution`-field, which is enum type, notice custom `x-enumNames` and modified `description` fields:

```
resolution: {
    format: "int32",
    enum: [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ],
    type: "integer",
    x-enumNames: [
        "Hour",
        "Day",
        "Month",
        "Year"
    ],
    description: "1=Hour,2=Day,3=Month,4=Year"
}
```

Problem is that `SchemaFilter` does not extend enum types which are in **operation parameters**. For example following api-method has parameter `resolution`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<ReturnType>> GetData(Models.ResolutionEnum resolution)
```

And this produces following operation parameter definition to swagger.json (notice missing `x-EnumNames`):

```
{
    name: "resolution",
    in: "query",
    required: true,
    type: "integer",
    format: "int32",
    enum: [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ]
}
```

Is there any way mechanism to extend swagger enum-schemas which are part of method parameters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55850113/5789864) under this question, I found that there are multiple extension points in `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen` namespace. `IParameterFilter` is just what I want, and I was able to inject `x-enumNames` to method parameter definitions.

Following is parameter filter which I made:

```
public class ModifyParametersFilter : IParameterFilter
{
    public void Apply(IParameter parameter, ParameterFilterContext context)
    {
        var type = context.ParameterInfo?.ParameterType;
        if (type == null)
            return;
        if (type.IsEnum)
        {
            var names = Enum.GetNames(type);
            var values = Enum.GetValues(type);
            var desc = "";

            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                var intValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(value.GetType()));
                desc += $"{intValue}={value},";
            }
            desc = desc.TrimEnd(',');
            if (!parameter.Extensions.ContainsKey("x-enumNames"))
                parameter.Extensions.Add("x-enumNames", names);
        }
    }
}
```

As other filters, this can be activated in `Startup.cs` with following snippet:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    ..
    c.ParameterFilter<ModifyParametersFilter>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with an IDocumentFilter, I have injected `x-stuff` using it, here is a sample:

```
public class InjectXStuff : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument s, DocumentFilterContext c)
    {
        PathItem path = s.Paths.Where(x => x.Key.Contains("Values")).First().Value;
        path.Post.Parameters.FirstOrDefault().Extensions.Add("x-stuff", "123456");
    }
}
```

the problem there is that you need to know the path in advanced, not sure if there is a pattern you can use in your code to identify those that are enums...

Comment: I tried this and found actually better approach thank to your tip. There is multiple extension points and there is `IParameterFilter` which extends just method parameters. I Will write another answer based on my discovery..